# jQuery - ajax - post - json request - doesn't have post body in some URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I've been stuck at this for a while now. I have ajax request here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: UPDATE_USER_INFO_URL ,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({user:'user'}),
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        if(data["statusCode"] && data["statusCode"] == 1) {
            _callback(1,data);
        }
        else {
            _callback(0,data);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus){
        _callback(0, {});
    }           
});
```

If I set `UPDATE_USER_INFO_URL` to a specific URL, fiddler show nothing in the body. If I set `UPDATE_USER_INFO_URL` to something else (even invalid URL), it does put `{user:'user'}` in the body in fiddler.

With original UPDATE_USER_INFO_URL:

```
POST http://10.35.50.26:8080/SelfServiceWs/user/session/upduserinfo HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, ; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://10.35.50.26:8080/SelfService/
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: 10.35.50.26:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0BF9D9CCCE9030E60AB0BCE5F6562CD8
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbAdAAAADw==
Content-Length: 0
```

Chage url to /SelfServiceWs/abcdef

```
POST http://10.35.50.26:8080/SelfServiceWs/abcdef HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://10.35.50.26:8080/SelfService/
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: 10.35.50.26:8080
Content-Length: 15
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9E79779805579A7964E03AAD76DF043B

{"user":"user"}
```

I have many other ajax calls, all are working as expected.

It must be little thing that I am missing.

Comment: Why do you need to send the data with JSON.stringify? Why don't you try just with _data: {user: 'user'}_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

I have an authentication servlet filter to url /user/ssoauth, unexpectedly (to me), it made eveything call to URL under /user path (including /user/session/upduserinfo) to send out Authorization header. Moved filter to /user/auth/ssoauth stop client to send authorization header when calling user/session/upduserinfo and fix the problem.

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/user/ssoauth</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

cause every client call to URL after /user to send Authorization header.

I learned something new today!

Comment: thanks! I had the same problem, only my auth service/filter was a php script serving an nginx auth subrequest.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data: JSON.stringify({'user':'user'}),
```

Comment: No luck here. Also, `JSON.stringify({user:'user'})` does work with different URL. I noticed the different between the two requests  that the first one is sending authorization header. I am trying to figure it out why it's doing that.